# What is Cordova, and how does it relate to PhoneGap?

Tags: apache, cordova

I understand that PhoneGap was acquired by Adobe, and that now it has been assimilated into Cordova (Part of Apache). But what does all this mean? Are they the same product? Or two separate entities?

Comment: Here's a pretty good blog post about it: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

PhoneGap was an open source project started by a company called Nitobi. As part of Nitobi's purchase by Adobe, because the PhoneGap project had many contributors from large companies like IBM etc, the project was contributed to the Apache Software Foundation.

At first the name was changed to "Callback", but then was renamed to "Cordova" (after the street the Nitobi offices were on at some point). This is because unlike the project itself, the *name* PhoneGap *is* part of Adobe's purchase of Nitobi.

Actually... as Brian Leroux put it himself: "PhoneGap is powered by Cordova. Think: webkit to safari."

http://blogs.nitobi.com/andre/index.php/2011/10/03/nitobi-enters-into-acquisition-agreement-with-adobe/

As for the GitHub project linked to in @TDeBailleul's answer, I suspect that nostalgia over the street name led Brian to name one of his projects "Cordova", however, that "Cordova" has not been updated in 9 months and is not the Apache Software Foundation incubator project "Cordova".

http://incubator.apache.org/projects/callback.html

The brand new shiny Cordova web page is up now and may shine even more light on the subject.

http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/

**Update**: In the time since I posted this answer, some things have changed and there are actually some differences now, mostly around the CLI Tooling.

So I wrote and update: http://blog.devgeeks.org/post/73789983750/cordova-vs-phonegap-an-update

Comment: ..and as of 1.5, the name PhoneGap has begun to be phased out of the software itself.

Comment: So to put a long story short, has Cordova replaced PhoneGap? 

How come there are still two separate websites, both appearing to have the same framework, but with completely different names, branding... and even documentation by the looks of things?

Comment: in the meantime cordova has passed incubation process, therefor new site is: http://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: From the updated post: "TL;DR: If you don’t need to use the cloud build service at PhoneGap Build, just use the Cordova CLI tools, not the PhoneGap ones."

Answer (score 6):

here a blog post that explain how both phonegap and cordova are here to stay:
[PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

Comment: Sorry, the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/brianleroux/cordova README.md

> A PhoneGap project toolchain that automates common tasks for building
>   cross platform mobile projects with OS X.
>
> Automate common development workflow tasks such as: compiling,
>   debugging, testing, releasing and other things in between. As an added
>   benefit projects generated with Cordova create a consistent,
>   predictable, easy to understand and therefor extend software project.
>   A number of conventions are introduced removing the need for mobile
>   developers to relearn their tools or, worse, rebuild them for every
>   project.

PhoneGap and Cordova are not the same, Cordova is a toolchain that enhances PhoneGap project developments