# What's the relation and difference between Apache Cordova and PhoneGap?

Tags: apache, cordova

What's the relation and difference between Apache Cordova and PhoneGap?
And what's the pros and cons respectively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Cordova, and how does it relate to PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384738/what-is-cordova-and-how-does-it-relate-to-phonegap)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318424/how-do-adobe-phonegap-and-apache-cordova-differ?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

'Adobe PhoneGap' is a distribution of 'Apache Cordova'. 
You can think of 'Apache Cordova' as the engine that powers 'PhoneGap', similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari.

'PhoneGap' distribution may contain additional tools that tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an Apache project.

For local builds phonegap CLI uses cordova CLI.

If your goal is to build cross platform apps with HTML, JS and CSS then use 'PhoneGap' for everything you need while 'Apache Cordova' is the destination for those interested in contributing to the open source project powering 'PhoneGap'.

You can find more details on-

[Is there a difference between PhoneGap and Cordova commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands)

http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what’s-in-a-name/

Answer (score 0):

Cordova : PhoneGap :: Webkit : Safari(Chrome).

Cordova powers PhoneGap, but fundamentally both represent the same thing as of now.

Sooner or later, PhoneGap 'the name' will die and what remains will be the Apache Software Foudation's Cordova.

Hope I haven't confused you further.

Comment: Actually, PhoneGap 'the name' isn't going anywhere. It will exist indefinitely for both *PhoneGap Build* and also for Adobe's custom distribution of Cordova. Just as RedHat is a distro of Linux, so with PhoneGap. AFAIK, there are not yet any differences in the official distribution, but there likely will be, once they feel the base product is secure enough. Further, you could argue that some features that are attributed to 'PhoneGap Build', like Hydration, are actually part of the distro. Either way, 'the name' isn't going anywhere. Which is a shame, because the difference confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cordova
what is Apache Cordova? Many people have been confusing the Apache Cordova with PhoneGap, but why there is this confusion?

As the name suggests, is a project maintained by the Apache foundation, his goal is to be an open-source framework for deploying applications developed in HTML / JS / CSS on several mobile platforms. That is:

Its development is maintained by the Apache Foundation
It is open-source, you can follow and contribute to its development
His focus is portability the same code between different platforms
And Phonegap?

The PhoneGap is a product maintained by Adobe, which aims to use the framework Apache Cordova, however, provide new resources for the developer. We can then define the PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova, with “something more”. Remember, the PhoneGap is an open-source project, you can also contribute to it and monitor his development.